# Problem with datetime conversion in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

Here is a reproduced example of my problem :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["2018-01-13 17:25:54+0100",
    "2018-01-13 07:23:36+0100",
    "2018-01-13 08:15:48+0100"], columns=["date"])

print(type(datetime.strptime(df["date"][1], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')))

print(type(pd.Series(df["date"].apply(lambda s: datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z')))[1]))
```

The output are :

*class 'datetime.datetime'*

*class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'*

How can I get a datetime.datetime object by using the apply function (or a similar one)?

Comment: pd.to_datetime(df.date) will help you to get datetime64. This your pandas equivalent  to datetime.datetime you can do almost the same operations

Answer (score 1):

#### Use Pandas methods for `datetime` operations

In general, *avoid* the `datetime` module from the standard library when dealing with Pandas dataframes. You *should* want to use vectorised operations, and *should* rely on Pandas methods taking advantage of NumPy-based vectorisation:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

print(df['date'].dtype)
# datetime64[ns]
```

#### But if you insist...

If you wish to export to an array of `datetime.datetime` values for use outside of Pandas, you can use [`to_pydatetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_pydatetime.html):

```
py_date = df['date'].dt.to_pydatetime()
# array([datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 13, 16, 25, 54),
#        datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 13, 6, 23, 36),
#        datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 13, 7, 15, 48)], dtype=object)
```

However, once you are using Pandas there's rarely a need to do so.